# How to specify field width with a variable?

Tags: c

I wanted to know if you can use a variable to specify field width, for example:

```
float g = 123.4567;
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
printf("%(%d).(%d)f", x,y,g);
I want my output to be: "123.4567", basically the same as

printf("%3.4f");
```

I don't think the compiler will read the current format, but maybe there is another way.

Comment: You surely didn't mean the `Q` javascript library, but did you mean the Q language? Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: @Bergi It's not Q language.

Comment: Flagging to close as unclear, as there's no indication of what programming language this is. (It isn't lolcode.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this question about C? I saw the q tag but I'm not sure, as you talk about compiler...

Anyway, in C it is done with `*`:

> `*`   The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.
>
> `.*`  The precision is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted.

```
printf ("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10);
Width trick:    10
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/